# Enforce to call a method when an object is created

Tags: java

I want to refactor the validation of requests in my project.
Right now I have a lot of code like this:

```java
if (condition1) {
    throw new HttpException("message1", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
} else if (condition2) {
    throw new HttpException("message2", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

I could create this method:

```java
 private static void require(final boolean value, final String message) {
    if (!value) {
        throw new HttpException(message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
 }
```

and use `require(condition, "Error message");`

But I really wanted it to be more readable because conditions and messages can be long and take more than one line.

I created builder like class:

```java
 public class HttpRequire {
    public static BuilderMsg require(final boolean value) {
        return  message -> {
            if (!value) {
                throw new HttpException(message, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        };
    }
    public interface BuilderMsg {
        void message(String message);
    }
}
```

And now you can do this: `require(condition).message("Error message");`

The problem is that it doesn't force a client to call `message()` method. If one forgot to add it and uses just `require(condition)`, the exception will never be thrown.

Is there a way to throw an error in compile stage if someone forgot to call `message()`?

Maybe some kind of annotation to check if an object has been created then its method must be called.

Comment: *"it doesn't force a client to call `message()` method"* - it doesn't seem obvious since you didn't share `BuilderMsg`, or I'm missing something? Can you provide a complete usage example?

Comment: You could write a static code analyzer or use an existing one (e.g. ArchUnit) to verify that each and every call to `require` is followed directly by a `message` call.

Comment: Also note how your class is _very_ similar to AssertJ's `Assertions.assertThat`. It's very easy to forget the actual assertion.